# Export-Mailbox cmdlet not deleting emails

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2007, powershell-cmdlet

I've got an issue with using Export-Mailbox cmdlet in Powershell  to delete emails between two dates from a mailbox. The current code that I am running is:

```
Export-Mailbox -Identity mailboxname -StartDate "01/11/2009 00:00:01" -EndDate "14/11/2009 00:00:01" -DeleteContent
```

I know there are emails that fall between these two dates, but every time the command runs and completes but gives a status message of "Error occurred in the step: Moving messages. Failed to copy messages to the destination mailbox store with error: An unknown error has occured."

Has any had success with using Export-Mailbox to delete messages, or know why this is erroring out?

Thanks.

- Jonny

~~~ SOLUTION ~~~

Using the help from David I ran the command again as follows:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity jonny | Export-Mailbox -TargetMailbox target -TargetFolder folder -EndDate "14/11/09 00:01:00" -StartDate "14/11/09 00:00:00" -DeleteContent
```

This worked as long as there weren't any more than 3000 emails in that timespan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity Jonny | Export-Mailbox -TargetMailbox mailboxname -StartDate "01/11/2009 00:00:01" -EndDate "14/11/2009 00:00:01" -DeleteContent
```

See [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/exchange/goodbye-exchange-exmerge,-hello-export-mailbox/) for more info about the most common problems using Export-Mailbox:

> The most common problems with using
>   Export-Mailbox are related to
>   permissions.  To use Export-Mailbox
>   you need to be delegated the Exchange
>   Server Administrator role, be a member
>   of the local Administrators group for
>   the target server, and have full
>   access to the source and destination
>   mailboxes.  The source and destination
>   mailboxes must be in the same Active
>   Directory forest.
>
> These are some common
>   permissions-related errors:
>
> **ERROR**
>
> - The specified mailbox database [Mailbox Database Name] does not exist
>
> **CAUSE** The user running the Export-Mailbox command needs to be
>   delegated the Exchange Administrator
>   role for the Exchange server.
>
> **ERROR**
>
> - Error occurred in the step: Creating target folder in the target mailbox. An unknown error has occurred., errorcode: -2147221233
>
> **CAUSE**
>   The user running the Export-Mailbox does not have full access to the destination mailbox.
>
> **ERROR**
>
> - Error occurred in the step: Moving messages. Failed to copy messages to the destination mailbox store with error: MAPI or an unspecified service provider. ID no: 00000000-0000-00000000, error code: -1056749164”
>
> **CAUSE** 
>   The user running the Export-Mailbox does not have full
>   access to the destination mailbox.

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for responding. I've just tried it that way, but it has the same effect.

Comment: Hi David, After much playing around I have got it working! 

You were correct about the permissions, but what was strange was that I had full access to both mailboxes.

However the other reason it was failing was because it was trying to delete too many emails in one go. When I ran it for a shorter time span, for example 1 minute, it worked perfectly!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting below error, I moved source mailbox to another store and it then worked.

> •Error occurred in the step: Moving messages. Failed to copy messages
>   to the destination mailbox store with error: MAPI or an unspecified
>   service provider. ID no: 00000000-0000-00000000, error code:
>   -1056749164”

Comment: That's interesting. I might try that, the mailbox itself is currently on it's own store as it is, but I will give this ago.